# spring-cloud-aws. Manual deletion of SQS messages after messages being processed successfully

Tags: spring-cloud

The current implementation of SimpleMessageListenerContainer class in Spring Cloud AWS (1.0.0.RC2) seems to automatically delete the message after the message handler finishes processing the message and the method call returns.

In our apps, we need to be able the process the message and wait for async acknowledgement from downstream queue before deleting the message from SQS upstream queue. Something like

Receive SQS msg -> Process msg -> Publish msg to RabbitMQ (thread completes here)

Delete SQS msg <- our app <- RabbitMQ Msg success Ack (asynchronously)

As the msg ack comes back asynchronously via a different thread, we need the option to manual delete msg from SQS once we've checked the success ack.

Ideally, the SimpleMessageListener should be configurable for which mode it is running in (auto delete or manual delete).

We'd very much like to use the spring aws cloud lib (vs rolling out our own) to integrate with SQS as it already takes care of listener container bean life-cycle management.

Please let me know if the above suggested feature is considered feasible and if so, when it can be implemented and released.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We could add one more flag (in addition to the already existing *deleteMessageOnException* flag) to completely disable the auto deletion of messages even when successfully processed. The problem I see is that poison messages are not handled anymore and could blow up the queue. I created an issue for that [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/51).

You will have another problem with your approach. If the message is not deleted quickly enough (based on the visibility timeout) it will come again in your handler method.

Receive SQS msg1 -> Process msg1 -> Publish msg1 to RabbitMQ (thread completes here)

Receive SQS msg2 -> Process msg2 -> Publish msg2 to RabbitMQ (thread completes here)

Receive SQS msg1 -> Process msg1 -> Publish msg1 to RabbitMQ **msg1 comes again because it was not deleted**

Delete SQS msg1 <- our app <- RabbitMQ Msg1 success Ack (asynchronously)

A **very** ugly workaround for now could be to throw an exception in your handler method and set the *deleteMessageOnException* flag to *false*. Therefore no messages will be deleted and you can get the receipt handle (with *@Header* or *@Headers*) to delete them manually.

**EDIT**

The issue is now fixed and one can define the deletion policy directly with the `@SqsListener` annotation and use an injected Acknowledgment object. See the last comment on [this issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/51)

Comment: When auto deletion is completely disabled, it is the application's responsibility to handle message duplication. I think it's a reasonable trade-off. In this way, it gives application more control on the life cycle of the messages. The same applies to handling poison messages. By poison message, I mean if the JSON payload is invalid or with corrupted content, the application should have a chance to decide how the message should be handled (deleted or dead-lettered).